# Pyqtgraph clip line

Tags: python-2.7, pyqtgraph

i'm trying to plot a smith chart in pyqtgraph. I would like to know if there is a method to clip
the ellipse items representing the imaginary circles with the real circle having radius = 1.
This is what i've done so far: i used the methods start angle e span angle of 
QGraphicsEllipse, but in this way a plot also the vertical and horizontal lines of the circle.
There's a method in matplotlib called set_clip_path(), do you know if there is something like this in pyqtgraph?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

plot = pg.plot()

plot.setAspectLocked()
plot.addLine(y=0)

#vector for real circle
rline = [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0]
#vector for imaginary
xline = [0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5]

circle1 = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(1, -1, -2, 2)
circle1.setPen(pg.mkPen(1))
plot.addItem(circle1)

for r in rline:
    raggio = 1./(1+r)
    circle = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(1, -raggio, -raggio*2, raggio*2)
    circle.setPen(pg.mkPen(0.2))
    plot.addItem(circle)

for x in xline:
    #printing the imaginary circle
    circle = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(x + 1, 0, -x*2, x*2)
    circle.setPen(pg.mkPen(0.2))
    circle.setStartAngle(1440)
    circle.setSpanAngle(1440)
    plot.addItem(circle)
```

EDIT

That's my final code

```
plot.setAspectLocked()
plot.setXRange(-1,1, padding = 0)
plot.setYRange(-1,1, padding = 0)
#plot.addLine(y=0)

rline = [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0]
xline = [0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5]

circle1 = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(1, -1, -2, 2)
circle1.setPen(pg.mkPen('w', width=0))
circle1.setFlag(circle1.ItemClipsChildrenToShape)
plot.addItem(circle1)

pathItem = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem()
path = pg.QtGui.QPainterPath()
path.moveTo(1, 0)

for r in rline:
    raggio = 1./(1+r)
    path.addEllipse(1, -raggio, -raggio*2, raggio*2)

for x in xline:
    path.arcTo(x + 1, 0, -x*2, x*2, 90, -180)
    path.moveTo(1, 0)
    path.arcTo(x + 1, 0, -x*2, -x*2, 270, 180)

pathItem.setPath(path)
pathItem.setPen(pg.mkPen('g', width = 0.2))
pathItem.setParentItem(circle1)
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipping is supported, but probably not the best option. A few possibilities:

1. Use [QGraphicsPathItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicspathitem.html) combined with [QPainterPath.arcTo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html#arcTo) to draw arcs without radial lines. This would also allow you to add multiple arcs to a single item rather than adding many items, which should improve performance.
2. Use Something like [PlotCurveItem](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotcurveitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotCurveItem.setData) or [arrayToQPath](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/functions.html#pyqtgraph.arrayToQPath) to manually draw your own arcs. If you use the `connect` argument, you'll again be able to generate multiple separate arcs on a single item.
3. Clipping is handled by Qt; see [QGraphicsItem.itemClipsToShape and QGraphicsItem.itemClipsChildrenToShape](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum). Beware: if you use this, you must set the pen width of the clipping object to 0 (Qt only partially supports cosmetic pens with width > 0). Example:

   ```
   import pyqtgraph as pg
   plot = pg.plot()

   e1 = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 4, 4)
   # MUST have width=0 here, or use a non-cosmetic pen:
   e1.setPen(pg.mkPen('r', width=0))
   e1.setFlag(e1.ItemClipsChildrenToShape)
   plot.addItem(e1)

   e2 = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(2, 2, 4, 4)
   e2.setPen(pg.mkPen('g'))
   e2.setParentItem(e1)
   ```

Comment: ok, thank you for the options. I'll try them, and i'll let you know

Comment: I use the first method to draw all the grid line (real part and imaginary part) and then clip the complete path with the module 1 circle. Thank you